# Getting current week days with dates

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to get current week dates

Lets think: today is Tuesday 07.05.2013. I want get a list of this week days with dates

How can I do this ?

```
Sunday 05.05.2013
Monday 06.05.2013
*Tuesday 07.05.2013
Wednesday 08.05.2013
Thursday 09.05.2013
Friday 10.05.2013
Saturday 11.05.2013
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code will work using system first day of week, that might be different from Sunday.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd.MM.yyyy");

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        Log.i("dateTag", sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
    }
```

Comment: yes, code starts with sunday, how can I start with monday ?  `setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);` starts 06.05; although today is sunday 05.05. I mean it would start monday 29.04 and last day will be sunday 05.05. is it possible ?

Comment: Do you want your code to work the same way regardless user current locale settings? If yes then just use `Calendar` instance for e.g. UK locale: `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.UK)`. UK Locale first day of week is Monday. Otherwise your code work respectively your current Locale and your Locale specify Sunday as first day of week, so that's way you have such behavior even if you setting Monday as first day of week.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ->

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);

int weekNo = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNo);

c.clear();

c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNo);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);


SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date startDate = c.getTime();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Log.d(formatter.format(c.getTime()));
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Comment: thanks, instead of using a certain date( 07.05.2013 ), how can do this for current date. I mean I want to get the week which the current date is in

Comment: You can do like this->

`c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, new Date().getDate());
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, new Date().getMonth());
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, new Date().getYear());`

Comment: Is there anyway to make first day monday instead of sunday... I used ` cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);`  It starts from monday but for example today is sunday 05.05.2013 , but list starts monday 06.05.2013 ... But I want to take week that sunday is last day, is it possible?